How to Center a Form Horizontally and Maintain a Fixed Vertical Position Across All Devices?
I'm working on a responsive web design and need to center a form horizontally while keeping it at a specific vertical position across different devices (desktop, tablet, and mobile). The form should overlay other elements without affecting the layout of the surrounding content.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Desktop view][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3znpuHlD.jpg
[mobile view][2]
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/mdQPk1ID.jpg
Here's what I have tried so far:
<div class="parent-element">
    <form class="centered-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

/* Ensure the parent element has a relative position */
.parent-element {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh; /* Ensures parent takes at least the full viewport height */
}

/* Style for the centered form */
.centered-form {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 200px; /* Fixed vertical position */
    width: 80%; /* Responsive width */
    max-width: 600px; /* Max width for larger screens */
    padding: 20px; /* Optional: padding for aesthetics */
    background-color: white; /* Optional: background color for better visibility */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Optional: shadow for better visibility */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Optional: rounded corners for aesthetics */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Ensures padding is included in width */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .centered-form {
        top: 250px; /* Adjust the top position for larger screens if needed */
    }
}

While the form centers correctly horizontally, it doesn't maintain a consistent vertical position across different devices as desired. On smaller screens, it either moves too high or too low.

How can I ensure that the form remains centered horizontally and maintains a fixed vertical position consistently across all devices? Any suggestions or improvements to my current approach would be greatly appreciated.

